# New installation fails - only get grub>

Tags: grub2, usb-installation

I have a computer running 20.04.  After failing to recover from a login loop I decided to reinstall 20.04 via usb thumb drive.  The installation proceeds to the 'unplug the USB drive and hit enter' phase of the installation.  The computer restarts and only shows a black screen with a `grub>` prompt.

There are two installation options.  One says 'remove Ubuntu 20.04 and reinstall' and another option to 'erase disk and install'.  I have tried both options and still get the grub menu.

Why can I not install fresh and how do I install Ubuntu?

Answer (score -1):

Changing the boot up option from uefi to legacy allowed the compututer to boot to the newly installed version of Ubuntu.